# Angular2 dont fire changeDetection after click

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-changedetection

Angular2 doesn't trigger the `ChangeDetection` after a click event. The code snippets below are to get the data from one component to another.

onClickEvent

```
 (click)="$event.preventDefault(); setApartmentObject(FlatObject)";
```

ApartmentOverviewComponent

```
constructor(private _apart:ApartmentService) {}

setApartmentObject(flat:ApartmentObject) {
    this._apart.setApartmentDetails(flat);
}
```

ApartmentService

```
Injectable()
export class ApartmentService {

  apartmentDetails:ApartmentObject

  getApartmentDetails():Observable<ApartmentObject> {
      return Observable.create((observer) => {
          observer.next(this.apartmentDetails);
          observer.complete();
      });
  }

  setApartmentDetails(value:ApartmentObject) {
      this.apartmentDetails = value;
  }
}
```

ApartmentDetailComponent

```
constructor(private _apart:ApartmentService)

get apartmentDetails() {
    this._apart.getApartmentDetails().subscribe(data => {
        this._apartmentDetails = data;
    });
    return this._apartmentDetails;
}
```

In the HTML file

```
 <p><strong>{{apartmentDetails.name || 'Musterwohnung'}}</strong></p>
```

I also tried to fix this problem with an eventemitter, but without success. Only the following dirty fix works:

```
constructor(private _ref:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  this._ref.detach();
  setInterval(() => {
     this._ref.detectChanges();
  }, 300);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Does Angular run change detection and you want to prevent it, or do you want change detection to run but Angular doesn't?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Why do you think Angular2 doesn't run change detection?

Comment: The problem is, angular should load the data from one object of the ApartmentOverviewComponent in the ApartmentDetailComponent and rerender with the actual data. I get the data in the ApartmentDetailComponent, but the view dont rerender, because the changeDetection dont trigger. And I dont know why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not related to change detection not running. Do you get any error or warning in the browser console?

Comment: No errors and no warnings in the console. The apartmentDetails() function set the data correctly, but angular dont rerender the view.

Comment: Where does `FlatObject` in `setApartmentObject(FlatObject)"` come from? Looks like a typo. Property names are usually lowercase and type names uppercase. Types can't be used this way in the template.

Comment: Can you put a console statement in get apartmentDetails() subscription function to check if subscription is invoked. Before this statement 'this._apartmentDetails = data;'.  I think you need to send a next value of observer from service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code that actually prevent the value from being read.

First of all—in your service—when you set the value, you just do it on the service's instance, instead of feeding it to the observable object. The observable just can't know that value has changed, so it won't emit the change (next) event. This is why the `ApartmentOverviewComponent. setApartmentObject()` does nothing. To actually feed the observable with data, you need to use a Subject.

In the ApartmentDetailComponent, in this simple scenario (where data is always synchronously provided), you could get the value in the way you try it. But, as mentioned before, the data won't ever change. It's also needles to store the data on the component's instance's `_apartmentDetails` field. You could use the observable in your template.

The working implementation is like that:

```
@Injectable()
class ApartmentService {
  // BehaviorSubject is a type of an Observable that can be manually fed with data
  // and returns it's last value to any subscriber.
  apartmentDetails = new BehaviorSubject<ApartmentObject>({name: 'Musterwohnung'});

  // Instead of using a property of the service, just inform the
  // subject about knew data and let it spread the change for you.
  setApartmentDetails(value: ApartmentObject) {
    this.apartmentDetails.next(value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'overview-cmp',
  // Side note: you don't need to .preventDefault() here.
  template: `<a (click)="setApartmentObject({name: 'Shiny Aparament'})">click</a>`
})
class ApartmentOverviewComponent {
  constructor(private apartService: ApartmentService) {}

  // Works same as before.
  setApartmentObject(flat: ApartmentObject) {
    this.apartService.setApartmentDetails(flat);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'details-cmp',
  // Use the 'async' pipe to access the data stored in an Observable
  // object. Also, to secure the code, use '?' to safely access the property.
  template: `<p><strong>{{(details | async)?.name}}</strong></p>`
})
class Apartament {
  // This is the observable with data.
  details: Observable<ApartmentObject>;

  constructor(private apartService: ApartmentService) {}

  // When component initialises, assign the observable data from the service
  ngOnInit() {
    this.details = this.apartService.apartmentDetails;
  }
}
```